# BufferedReader wont progress, keeps waiting for input

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

I'm trying to make a program that reads input from the user
and combines them into one variable.

This is what I'm trying to use:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String content = "";
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    content = content + " " + line;
}
System.out.println(content);
```

I've tried some alternatives for the `while` loop but the problem persists.
It wont progress to `println`.

Please Help, thank you!

Comment: use `hasNextLine()`

Comment: Under what condition should the `while` loop stop? Logically speaking, what input of *you*, the user, should cause the loop to end?

Comment: Usually `^D` or `^Z` to signal eof.

Comment: Waiting for inout is what it's supposed to do. Unclear what you're asking. Possibly you think it should return null when there is no current input to be read, but that's not what it says I'm the Javadoc.

Comment: @luk2302 I want it to stop right after I've given an input, or should I use a different class than bufferedreader?

Comment: why don't you use scanner?

Comment: So if you want to stop after an input ,why are you looping until it returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `while((line = br.readLine()) != null)` loop is the issue here.
It isn't clear when you want to stop it, so I would suggest:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("terminating string")) {
   content = content + " " + line;
}
```

This way, you append `line` to `content` until `line` is different from `"terminating string"`.